# Load Data from Handsontable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am using Handsontable 0.7.3 to read from a XLS file and view in the Web Browser. Now i want to read that table to create a new XLS file but i dont know what i need to do. My code:

```
  $('#example').handsontable({
        data: data,
        startCols: 4,
        colHeaders: true,
        rowHeaders: true,
        fillHandle: true,
        colHeaders: ["<b> Nombre </b>", "<b> Compania </b>", " <b> Codigo </b>","<b> Ciudad </b>"],
        contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row']
      });         

      $('#ver').html($('#example').data('handsontable').version);
```

¿Any idea? Thanks for all and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Handsontable cannot read XLS files. It only works with JavaScript arrays and objects (JSON). Do you have some tool that converts XLS<->JSON?

Answer (score -1):

Hi if my understanding is correct you want to upload the data from handsontable to XLS file right..?
u can use "getData" method in handsontable which will return all the data present in table.
by using string tokenizer delimit the data. By iterating those tokens add newline characters.
Then use

```
httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write("ur content");
```

to genearte XLS file.